# Is identification assumption a necessary condition for causal inference?

Tags: estimation, causality, assumptions, identifiability

I am confused about the identification assumptions mentioned in learning pearls causal inference book .

May I ask is identification assumption a necessary condition for causal inference?

Comment: Can you edit your question to describe how the "identification" assumption is defined?